# error TypeError: Cannot read property '_options' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, thingsboard

I clone thingsboard from their github repo. But when I am going to build the production I am getting an error. In console it give me something  like this.

```html
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property '_options' of undefined
See "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-GjvaXO\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I use 'ng build --prod --vendor-chunk' to build production.

Inside angular-errors.log is like below.

```html
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property '_options' of undefined
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\HomeOffice\hydroanalytica\thingsboard\ui-ngx\extra-webpack.config.js:60:58)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\HomeOffice\hydroanalytica\thingsboard\ui-ngx\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\dist\custom-webpack-builder.js:30:24)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\HomeOffice\hydroanalytica\thingsboard\ui-ngx\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\dist\custom-webpack-builder.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\HomeOffice\hydroanalytica\thingsboard\ui-ngx\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\dist\custom-webpack-builder.js:4:12)
    at Function.buildWebpackConfig (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\HomeOffice\hydroanalytica\thingsboard\ui-ngx\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\dist\custom-webpack-builder.js:19:16)
    at browserWebpackConfig (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\HomeOffice\hydroanalytica\thingsboard\ui-ngx\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\dist\common.js:17:58)
    at initialize (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\HomeOffice\hydroanalytica\thingsboard\ui-ngx\node_modules\@angular-builders\custom-webpack\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js:111:35)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I don't know why I am getting this error. Is there any solution?

Comment: What is inside of: angular-errors.log?